# separating number in array of digits C#

Tags: c#, arrays, digits

i am new in programming and for now only practicing with C#. So my problem is: i am trying to separate a number in a digits with array (example: number 12345 in to digits {1,2,3,4,5}). I make some code, here is it:

```
  int num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] digits = new int[3];
        int separatedDigit = 0;


        for (int i = num; num != 0; i--)
        {
            digits[i] = num  % 10;
            num = num / 10;

        }
```

but it shows me error " Index was outside the bounds of the array." I suppose the problem is coming from that "for" part because it starts from position 3 and the array have only 2 (0, 1, 2). I don't know how to fix it, so can someone help me?

Comment: Position #3, is actually referenced as [2], since you start at position [0]

Comment: when your for loop starts, you are trying to do like `digits[12345] = 5`, which .net runtime woudn't allow as index '12345' doesn't exist in the array.

Comment: 12345 is just example in my situation the number is allays 3 digits long...

Comment: how to make it to start form position 0 because i tried  


 for (int i = 0; num != 0; i++)
            {
                digits[i] = num  % 10;
                num = num / 10;
                
            } 

but still didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`i` starts out as equal to `num`, which in turn starts out as the number that you entered, which can be far greater than 3. For example, if I put in `123` as the input number, then the loop first tries to access `digits[123]` which is *waaaaaay* outside the bounds of that array.

You're going to want to tweak your for loop to get `i` to start at a more reasonable number:

```
for (int i = digits.Length - 1; num != 0; i--)
{
    // ...
```

Alternatively, you could start `i` at 0 and work your way up:

```
for (int i = 0; num != 0; i++)
{
    // ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try *Linq*: filter out `'0'`..`'9'` characters and *materialize* them into array:

```
int[] digits = Console
  .ReadLine()
  .Where(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9') // '0'..'9' characters only 
  .Select(c => c - '0')             // '0' should correspond to 0 integer
  .ToArray();
```

Comment: While this does the job, I feel like it doesn't address OP's core question. Keep in mind that OP is a beginner, and wants to know not just "what" but also "why".

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you haven't allocated the correct number of spaces when initialising the array, for example in the following line of code:
int[] digits = new int[3];.. Instead you should first read the input, calculate the number of numbers (characters) that were input and then allocate an array with that number of elements.. Remember that arrays start at the index of 0.. so in your example the first character (number) would be entered at digits[0].. then digits[1]... digit[2].. etc.. from within the loop until all the numbers have been input.

Try this code:

```
    string numberSequence = Console.ReadLine();
    var numberCount = numberSequence.Length;
    int[] digitArray = new int[numberCount];
    int i = 0;
    foreach (var number in numberSequence)
    {
        digitArray[i] = number;
        Console.WriteLine(number);
        i++;
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        int _num = 12345;
        var g = _num.ToString().Select(x => int.Parse(x.ToString())).ToArray<int>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 string strValue = "19345abc#/";
 char[] charArray = strValue.ToCharArray();
 List<int> list = new List<int>();
 for (int i = 0; i < charArray.Length; i++)
     {
       if (char.IsNumber(charArray[i]))
         {
           list.Add(charArray[i] - '0');
         }
     }
```